# Find and replace a string in a sentence to another string in a list of sentences using a dictionary

Tags: python, string, replace

I have hundreds of thousands of original sentences and a lookup table in the form of a dictionary. I need to find all keys in all sentences and replace them as the value of the corresponding key.

For example, the original sentences and the lookup table are

```
sentences = ['Seoul is a beautiful place', 'I want to visit Paris', 'New York New York',
 'Between Paris and New York'] 

lookup = {'Paris': 'France', 'New York': 'United States', 'Seoul': 'Korea'}
```

The desired result is as follows.

```
['Korea is a beautiful place', 'I want to visit France', 'United States United States', 
'Between France and United States']
```

What I tried is the below code.

```
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    sentence1 = sentences[I]
    for key in lookup.keys():
        sentence1 = sentence1.replace(key, lookup[key])
    sentences[i] = sentence1
```

I'm concerned that double loops may take too much time.
Is it the best way to do this?
Is there a faster or more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there a database?

Comment: @user2182349 No. It is stored as a Pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `re.sub` with a callback function.  Form a regex alternation of the city keys, and then do the lookup in the callback.

```py
sentences = ['Seoul is a beautiful place', 'I want to visit Paris', 'New York New York', 'Between Paris and New York']
lookup = {'Paris': 'France', 'New York': 'United States', 'Seoul': 'Korea'}
regex = r'\b(?:' + r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in lookup.keys()]) + r')\b'
output = [re.sub(regex, lambda m: lookup[m.group()], x) for x in sentences]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['Korea is a beautiful place',
 'I want to visit France',
 'United States United States',
 'Between France and United States']
```

Comment: Way too complicated for a simple task

Answer (score 0):

You just have to loop trough all sentences then replace every element:

```
sentences_corrected = []
for sentence in sentences:
    for key, substitution in lookup.items():
        sentence = sentence.replace(key, substitution)
    sentences_corrected.append(sentence)
```

Comment: This approach may lead to problems.  For instance, there are two countries `Niger` and `Nigeria`.  Going by your logic, the sentence `Nigeria is fun` might get a substitution on `Niger`, which in fact this should not be happening.  See my answer which uses regular expressions to get around this problem.